# What statistical analysis should I use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, frequency

I have this set of data (I altered it here), and I have no idea what statistical analysis to use for it. Any help would be appreciated, I know that I cannot use a chi squared, as it did not work. 
The percentages are simply independent variables that are not actually data.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZUD2zGUybh0-CfQuYBN0nUUX5Tjq5n1DgIIsgQWK42g/edit

Comment: Can you please give more detail on your data? i.e. what is it in relation to, what relationship are you trying to analyse, etc.

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  It is preferred that questions and answers on this site are self contained; as a result, it would be better if you replicated your information from your document in your question.  Also, if you torture numbers long enough, they will confess to anything, so it really is helpful if you state upfront what it is that you are hoping to get out of your data.

Comment: I am analyzing the reaction of a solution to Benedict's Raegant. This is a solution that detects the presence of glucose by causing a solution to change color. The change order in my data signifies the order in which the colors changed for each percentage.

Comment: The percentages represent the salinity percentage of each solution. Also, the table's rows and columns always total up to 10 because I performed ten trials of this experiment. I am aiming to prove my hypothesis correct that the lower percentage of salinity the quicker it will change aka be closest to change order 1.

Comment: You should edit that information (the linked data & your comment / explanations) into the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is that the change order increases as salinity increases. The change order is an ordinal variable and the salinity is a continuous variable.

You probably don't expect the effect of the salinity to be linear, from my limited chemistry knowledge the difference between the effect of 0% and 10% salinity is probably greater than the difference between the effect of 30% and 40% salinity. Because of this I think that it is better to treat the salinity as an ordinal variable, this avoids assumptions if you did regression or something like that.

Therefore you want to test if one ordinal variable is positively correlated with another ordinal variable.

As the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/ordinal-dependent-variable-and-ordinal-independent-variable-which-test-to-perfo) suggests you can use the [Spearman rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient), you can do hypothesis tests on this correlation coefficient to test if it is greater than 0.

In total you recorded 50 values in your table, to use the test you should put all 50 observations into a list rather than summarized as totals. Using this statistical test requires you to treat the 50 values as independent, clearly that's not exactly true because for the same experiment you cannot find that both 0% and 10% have a change order of 1. However, I think that using this test is suitable for your case.

Comment: I'll look into the Spearman's Rank correlation coefficient and try to apply it to my data. Much appreciated for the help!